# Sequential continuity of linear operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces, generalized-functions

Let $u\colon L\to M$ be a linear map of locally convex linear topological vector spaces.
Assume that $u$ is sequentually continuous, i.e. maps convergent sequences to convergent ones.
(This notion is formally weaker that the usual topological continuity in the case of non-metrizable spaces.) Let $L_0\subset L$ be a topologically dense linear subspace. Assume that
$u|_{L_0}\equiv 0$.

**QUESTION: Does it follow that $u\equiv 0$?**

I am interested in rather concrete examples of spaces: spaces of generalized functions on smooth manifolds (say $R ^n$) with the wave-front set contained in a given closed set.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take $c(\Gamma)$ with $\Gamma$ uncountable under the topology of pointwise convergence. $c_0(\Gamma)$ is dense but not sequentially dense. Let $u$ be the linear functional that vanishes on $c_0(\Gamma)$ and is one at $1_\Gamma$.

Comment: Product space $\ \mathbb R^A\ $ for uncountable $\ A\ $ works like this too (but my poor brainy malfunctions from time to time, too often).